# Trying to get an image to alert in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm quite new to HTML and coding; I'm working on a very basic webpage which revolves around Gaming. Although this is probably answer somewhere else, I haven't been able to get a straight forward answer. Please bear in mind that I'm new to the block so I will not understand more advanced terminology.

```js
function myFunction {
 alert("Invoker is a ranged intelligence hero who is very difficult to master. He is unique in that he possesses a total of 14 abilities in his arsenal; three of them - Quas, Wex, and Exort - are reagents and one is his special ultimate Invoke. The three abilities he learns throughout leveling up can have three instances, which serve as the basic ingredients or components for him to create a new ability using his ultimate. Once the reagents or elements are combined, he can invoke one out of ten different abilities. All of his invoked abilities are capable of a multitude of actions, from damaging enemies to aiding his allies, and even saving himself from danger. His three reagents can be upgraded up to level 7 which determines the power and potency of his invoked abilities, making it more powerful than an ordinary spell. Because of this, he can be played in almost any role possible. Invoker can be a carry, semi-carry, ganker, pusher, initiator or even support. His three reagents provide passive attributes with each level, and each instance of his reagents provides a passive bonus, allowing for specialization at early levels and situational boosts at later levels. His extremely flexible nature allows him to use many different combinations of items effectively but also make him dependent on solid builds and a good gold advantage. Because of the extra points needed to level his three reagents, Invoker also has a special Attribute Bonus ability at level 25 that allows him to gain 6 points in all stats.");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>ICT</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="Style 1.css">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Dota2 Heroes Alarm.js">
 </script>
</head>



<body bgcolor=blue>


 <div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 40px;"> 
    <img src="Invoker_Icon.png" width="32" height="32" onclick="myFunction;" />
</div>
```

When I click on the image,"Invoker_Icon.png", it does not create an alert box.

Thank you in advance, it has been bugging me a lot.

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: notice that when you run the code here on stack overflow, it shows an error. that's called the javascript console. you can access the same console on your website by opening your browser's "developer tools" (usually the f12 key) when your site is open and finding the "console" tab (whose icon usually looks like `>_`). then when it shows errors, you can google the error to learn what might be causing it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually call the function, by adding parenthesis.

Your handler attribute code doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include `()`:

```
onclick="myFunction;"
```

so you're not actually calling your function. You're just sticking a reference to the function's internal representation into that onclick, which doesn't do anything. It's like having `1;` -also doesn't do anything. it just sticks a `1` there.

Try

```
onclick="myFunction();"
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have corrected that now but sadly it's still not working.

Comment: In Developer tools, it says that 'myFunction' is undefined. Is that of any help?

Comment: check the console, make sure your external JS file loaded properly.

Comment: SCRIPT5009: 'myFunction' is undefined             That is what the console says when I click on the image

Comment: so where/how do you define the function, and how to you get it into the page?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that but the function myFunction is in a separate js file linked to the asp/html page. I used this to link the js file: <script type="text/javascript" src="Dota2 Heroes Alarm.js">
 </script>

Comment: and I like I said before, check that the file is properly being loaded.

Comment: How do I check that?